# How can I print a locale aware date using Zend_Date?

Tags: zend-framework, date

I'd like to use Zend_Date to print out the previous 2 months and year as a string e.g.:

July 2009
June 2009

I need it to be locale aware so that if the code runs with the locale set to, say, German, the month names will print in German.

```
  $date = new Zend_Date();
    $date->subMonth(1);
    echo $date->get(Zend_date::MONTH_NAME).' '.$date->get(Zend_Date::YEAR);
    $date->subMonth(1);
    echo $date->get(Zend_date::MONTH_NAME).' '.$date->get(Zend_Date::YEAR);
```

Is this all I need to do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the locale when creating the Zend_Date object. Like this:

```
$date = new Zend_Date(new Zend_Locale('de_AT'));
$date->subMonth(1);
echo $date->get(Zend_date::MONTH_NAME).' '.$date->get(Zend_Date::YEAR);
$date->subMonth(1);
echo $date->get(Zend_date::MONTH_NAME).' '.$date->get(Zend_Date::YEAR);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the optional locale parameter in the get method:

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::MONTH_NAME,'de_DE');
echo $date->get(Zend_Date::MONTH_NAME,'en_UK');
```